# asp.net mvc 4.5 adding view by visual studio wizard

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcAution.Models.Auction', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcAution.Models.Auction]'.

Please help me how to solve this error.

Comment: Please provide details of what have you done to get to this, for example snippets of code and/or steps.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution.
Your view has declared that it expects a model of type `IEnumerable<Auction>`
but you are passing it an `Auction` from your controller.  In your controller, simply add your single `Auction` value to a `List` and then pass that `List` to your view.

Here's how the view declares its model type (with the `@model` directive):

[image: view model declaration]

And here's how your controller invokes the view with data (with the `View` method):
[image: invocation of view by controller]

[Here's a longer explanation of the `@model` directive](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor).

Comment: yupp i accepted, it solved my problem :-) @ Jonathan Wilson